# how to concatenate strings to a void* in a struct using snprintf in C

Tags: c

I am trying to concatenate string to a void* using snprintf but I am getting segmentation fault for it.

```
  typedef struct __buf{
      void* ptr;
      size_t len;
    }

    buf val = {NULL, 100};

    int main(){
     snprintf(val->ptr, val->len, "%s%s", "hello", "world");
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `void *`?

Comment: @Ed Heal, because it can be any type of value and currently I have the need to use this void* to assign strings

Comment: Perhaps using `union` would be better

Comment: I did like this val->ptr = (void *)(strcat("hello","world"));

Comment: `val->ptr` points to `NULL`, you cannot use `snprintf` on that. You would need to allocate memory for it first.

Comment: You need to allocate memory for ptr, then cast it to char* to use sprintf.

Comment: Your code is not even close to being syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing

```
buf val = {NULL, 100};
```

`val.ptr` is pointing to `NULL`, of course `snprintf` will fail. You need to
allocate memory for it:

```
int main(void)
{
    val.ptr = calloc(val.len, 1);
    if(val.ptr == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "not enough memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    snprintf(val->ptr, val->len, "%s%s", "hello", "world");

    free(val.ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that

```
val->ptr = (void *)(strcat("hello","world"));
```

is very wrong. The first argument of `strcat` cannot be a pointer to a string
literal, because modifying string literals yields undefined behaviour and on most systems string literals are stored on read-only memory.
You'll need an array where you can modify the characters in the array:

```
char str[20] = "hello";
strcat(str, "world");
```

Comment: @SteveSummit right you are, the man page says *including the terminating null byte*. Thanks for the feedback, I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks for fixing.

Answer (score 1):

> how to concatenate strings to a void* in a struct using snprintf in C

The below is like `snprintf(NULL, 100, "%s%s", "hello", "world");` which attempts to write data to `NULL` - undefined behavior.

```
buf val = {NULL, 100};
snprintf(val->ptr, val->len, "%s%s", "hello", "world");
```

Instead allocate data as mentioned by [@Pablo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49639894/2410359)

---

To determine the memory needed, code can use the return value of `snprintf()` with first passing 0.

> The `snprintf` function returns the number of characters that would have been written had `n` been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative value if an encoding error occurred.   C11dr §7.21.6.5 3

```
int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s%s", "hello", "world");

if (len >= 0 && (val->ptr = malloc(len + 1u)) != NULL) {
  val->len = len + 1u;
  snprintf(val->ptr, 0, "%s%s", "hello", "world");
}
....
// Later free the memory.
free(val->ptr);
val->ptr = NULL;
val->len = 0;
```

---

BTW, recommend to use `size` in `struct __buf` is the *size* of the buffer is to be saved.